# AS3 Putting function blah(){ around code generates errors on lines of code I dont have

Tags: actionscript-3

I've got a block of code that's doing what I want - it generates a grid of MC's.

As soon as I put something like function blah() around it, it starts generating errors indicating lines of code I don't have e.g.

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
>       at flightCellMaker_fla::MainTimeline/myXMLtrace() [flightCellMaker_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:87]
>       at flightCellMaker_fla::MainTimeline/processFPBxml() [flightCellMaker_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:52]
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>       at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>       at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

When I take the function out, it does what I want it to do. What's up with that?

```
var testXML:XML;
var myFPBxml:XML;

// Initialise a URLLoader to get XML data from XML file
var myFPBLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myFPBLoader.load(new URLRequest("flightPlannerBoard.xml"));


 // Check XML data fully loaded
 myFPBLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processFPBxml);


// Once the flight board planning data is loaded, save it to a variable
function processFPBxml(e:Event):void {
myFPBxml = XML(e.target.data);
myXMLtrace();
 }  


// Grab the XML data load completed and make it available elsewhere
function myXMLtrace(){
testXML = XML(myFPBxml);
}
trace("***********************" + testXML.*); This throws an error (not within myXMLtrace tho)
```

OK, so here's the rest of the code that will run correctly on it's own but not in a function:

```
// Create and place all the flight cells for planning and drag and drop 

// Setup 2 loops: j for columns and i for Rows
for (var j:Number =0; j < rowNum; j++){

for (var i:Number =0; i<9; i++){

    // Create copies of flightCell for board grid
    var my_mc = new flightCell();
    my_mc.name = "mc"+i+j;

    addChild(my_mc);

    // Set event Listeners on all Child objects
    my_mc.myDragShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, fl_MouseOverHandler);
    my_mc.myDragShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, fl_MouseOutHandler);
    my_mc.myDragShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, fl_MouseDownHandler);
    my_mc.myDragShape.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, fl_MouseUpHandler);

    Object(this).my_mc.yellowHiLite.visible = false;


    //cellPos[j] = myXML.cellPosX[j];
    //trace(stage.myXML.*);

    //trace(my_mc.name);
        my_mc.x = (100 + colWidth);
        my_mc.y = myRowHeight;

    colWidth = colWidth + 155;

    //trace(myXML.*);

    cellArray[arrayCount] = [my_mc.x, my_mc.y];
    trace("CellArrayCount = " + cellArray[arrayCount]);
    arrayCount = arrayCount + 1;
}

myRowHeight = myRowHeight + 105;
colWidth = 50;
}
```

Comment: var testXML:XML;
var myFPBxml:XML;

// Initialise a URLLoader to get XML
var myFPBLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myFPBLoader.load(new URLRequest("flightPlannerBoard.xml"));


 // Check XML data loaded
 myFPBLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processFPBxml);
 
 
// Save it to a variable
function processFPBxml(e:Event):void {
 myFPBxml = new XML(e.target.data);
 myXMLtrace();
 } 


// Grab the XML data load completed and make it available elsewhere
function myXMLtrace(){
 testXML = new XML(myFPBxml);
   trace("***********************" + testXML.*);
 
}

Comment: Not in a comment :D It's unreadable. Edit your question.

Comment: Sorry - new to all this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trace is throwing an error because it is being executed before the XML is loaded.

ActionScript is asyncronous, which means that while the XML is being loaded, the program execution carries on going, and looks something like this:

1. Declare `testXML:XML` and `myFPBxml:XML`
2. Create loader and start loading
3. Add a listener for load completion
4. Trace `testXML`
5. Execute `processFPBxml` when the XML is loaded

If you move your trace into the `myXMLTrace` function then it will work correctly.

---

With the newly added code, the problem is with this line:

```
Object(this).my_mc.yellowHiLite.visible = false;
```

There is no need to use the `this` keyword at all here.  This will work inside or outside a function:

```
my_mc.yellowHiLite.visible = false;
```

The reason your code fails inside a function is because inside and outside the function `this` will be the scope of the object in which this code resides.  However, when you put the code into a function, the reference you create - `my_mc` - is scoped locally to the function, not to the parent object, and so `this.my_mc` is undefined, because `this` is not the function scope.

Comment: I know it will trace properly there but I need the value outside of the myXMLtrace function

Comment: You can access the value outside of the function, _but not until the XML is loaded_.

Comment: Got that bit... Which is why I have 2 functions. One is waiting for the COMPLETED event. The next is called from within that function to run the other code. The problem is, if I put the rest of the code I've made (which runs correctly) within the 2nd function, it throws an error. So, it's a circular problem...

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code?  Obviously something in that loses scope, but I can't debug what I can't see :)

Comment: I've edited the original to include the code that wont run inside a function.

Comment: YEP! That was it. Would you mind explaining why it was throwing errors, so I can learn for next time? I used the target helper in the coding window. Many thanks for the help! Phew!

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you taking the code out of the function it's currently in and calling the new function from where the code used to be? Or are you trying to define a function variable?
If you're only putting function blah() { ... } around code in the same place it is currently running, you'll get a syntax error for sure. In that case, try:

```
var blah:Function= function() { ... };
blah();
```

Comment: The reason I'm using a function is so that I can access the values from another function. I can't seem to get the variable value without calling a function from another function - so I'm stuck in an infinite regress! I have declared the variables outside the functions too...

Comment: Just changing the trace to: // Grab the XML data load completed and make it available elsewhere
function myXMLtrace(){
 testXML = XML(myFPBxml);
}
trace("***********************" + testXML.*); Throws an error

Answer (score 0):

If you declare variables within a function they fall inside the scope of the function only.

It sounds like you are trying to access variables from elsewhere in your code.

So what you need to do is declare your variables outside of the function. e.g.

```
var one:VarType;
var two:VarType;

function blah():void {
 trace(one);
}
```

Comment: Just wondering if: var myFPBxml:XML; is over written by myFPBxml = new XML(e.target.data); If so, I can't find a way to get (e.target.data) without throwing an error...

Comment: The xml held by myFPBxml would be overwritten yes. But once the function had done the overwriting you would access the xml by referencing myFPBxml, not e.target.data.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought but I keep getting: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference, if I trace myFPBxml outside the 2nd function - it's an infinite regress loop kinda thing! Must be missing something fundamental here...

Comment: I think using the asterisk as a wildcard might be the issue: trace("***********************" + testXML.*);. Try trace(testXML); and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't make any difference. It seems I'm going around in circles. I can access the value in a function, but if I put the rest of the code I'm running in a function, it throws an error. Perhaps there's a problem with the other code that only surfaces in a function...