# AS3 How do you declare a global variable?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I'm trying to get a value from a function which is a URLLoader COMPLETE event but even with declaring variables outside of the function will not allow me to get the value out. I'm stuck.

It seems that the Asynchronous nature of Flash makes it impossible to get a value out: e.g. this works:

```
// Initialise a URLLoader to get XML data from XML file
var myFPBLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myFPBLoader.load(new URLRequest("flightPlannerBoard.xml"));


// Check XML data fully loaded
myFPBLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processFPBxml);

var myXML:XML = new XML();// Declared **outside** function

function processFPBxml(e:Event):void {
this.myXML = XML(e.target.data);
trace("yep" + myXML); // This works
myTraceXML();
 }

function myTraceXML(){
 trace("more tests:" + myXML); // **This trace works**
}

trace("more tests:" + myXML); // This **doesn't** work
```

How do you get a value you can use whenever, wherever you want?

Comment: I explained why this doesn't work in your previous question, please don't create new questions for the same topic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 Putting function blah(){ around code generates errors on lines of code I dont have](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9464866/as3-putting-function-blah-around-code-generates-errors-on-lines-of-code-i-don)

Comment: You should remove this question and read the answer in the last one.

Comment: Thanks for the minuses! BUT the problem wasn't solved so I looked for a different perspective. I know why it DOESN'T work (as you explained), the problem is, the solution throws an error e.g. The rest of the code I want to run in the 2nd function. I was told in another question that this was to be expected. So now I've got circular answers 1) Put the code in a function, or 2) Don't put the code in a function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what is happening in your code:

1. functions `processFPBxml()`, `myTraceXML()` and variables `myFBPLoader` and `myXML` are declared.
2. XML starts loading `myFPBLoader.load`. **The code does not stop at this point. The loading is asynchronous call and the rest of the code is being executed immediately**.
3. an empty XML gets traced `trace("more tests:" + myXML); // This **doesn't** work`
4. XML is loaded and `Event.COMPLETE` is dispatched.
5. EventHandler assigned to the forementioned Event call the response: `processFPBxml()`. At this point the myXML is assigned to the downloaded data.
6. `myTraceXML()` is called.

Now if you want to continue code execution after the XML is loaded, you have to divide your code into separate functions that make specific tasks and call those functions after you get the data from XML. In this case, you could rename `myTraceXML()` to `init()` or anything that makes sense to you and write the rest of the program (not necessary in this particular function. Use it as the starting point).

Comment: Thanks. So it seems I have a circular problem. In one question I asked recently, I was told to NOT put my code in a function because it will give me an error - which is true. If I run the rest of the code outside a function it works fine. BUT when I try to use the myXML value it can't, for the reasons you stated above. SO, do I understand from the above, that I must have a function for my code and try to find out why it throws an error from within that function?

Comment: The most important thing to understand is the flow (execution) of the code. The order you declare functions will not neccessarily mean that they will be executed sequentially. Starting from line 1 you must understand what each line is doing and what can be expected at that point. If it seems difficult, then you simplify the code, break it down to functions. If that does not help, try debugging everything and pay attention to errors.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was shown the error in the code I wanted to wrap in the function - which only showed up when in a function and now I've learnt a whole lot in the process, so I appreciate your feedback. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, requested data through `URLLoader` is asynchronously obtained.

This means that the data you're after *cannot* be accessed until Flash has received it. What you are trying to do is illogical and cannot be done.

If it was possible, why would web applications have loading symbols and the like when looking for information to display?

Comment: I understand the async part. Which is why I have 2 functions. If I could put the rest of the code I need to run within the 2nd function, it would be fine. The trouble is, as soon as I wrap the code in function blah() {...} it throws an error. Which in another question someone said to keep it out of a function... so now I'm left with 2 answers a) Don't use a function b) Use a function. So, it seems I need to use a function and find out why the code doesn't like sitting in a  function... does that make sense?